# include directory based on condition in Cmake

Tags: c++, c, makefile, cmake

we have a tree shaped directory structure in our project like:

```
project_dir/public_include
public_include has dir1, dir2 and dir3
```

now, I want to include directories based on an option

```
if(option A)
 include_directories(project_dir/public_include/dir1)
else
 include_directories(project_dir/public_include/dir3
                     project_dir/public_include/dir2)
endif()
```

The header files are independent.

It is not working!!! Am I missing something???

Comment: include directories wher ? What is "not working" exactly ?

Comment: The only thing is you should write just `if(A)`. The `option` keyword is used only for option declaring.

Answer (score 0):

How about `options` ? Try using `option(option_A "include dir 1" ON)` at the top of your `CMakeLists.txt`. It will set `option_A=ON` by default and your `if` statement should work.